# Constraint to prevent 'duplicates' only when column > 0

Tags: postgresql, constraint, unique-constraint, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with a `fk` column that should be unique when another `int` column is `> 0`. If that sentence doesn't make sense, here is an example of valid rows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT fk,int
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 1, -12 ),
    ( 1,  20 ),
    ( 1,   0 )
  ) AS (fk, int);
```

Adding a new row to the table with a `fk` value of `1` and a `int` column that is `> 0` would be invalid.

Is there a way to do this with a constraint or index? I feel like an exclude constraint nearly gets me there, but I couldn't figure out a way to get it to work.

I'm using Postgres 9.6.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a conditional unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexName ON foo (fk) WHERE (int>0);
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7c5f4158a651b601e98b9ec57b1304f0)*